# Limiting number of form characters with Javascript validation

Tags: javascript, forms

How can I limit the number of characters that an input form allows?
I'm using a validation like this

```
//Last name
var x=document.forms["regForm"]["lname"].value
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Last name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
<script>

function testInput(obj, max_length){
    if(obj.value.length > max_length){
        alert(obj.name + "'s length is too long");
    }
}

</script>

<input name='lName' onchange='testInput(this, 8);'/>
<input name='fName' onchange='testInput(this, 15);'/>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/FQTM5/

Comment: Is there anyway it can look similar to the code I've entered?

Comment: @Mike where do you put your code, is it in any `onchange` (or any action) call?

Answer (score 2):

Why not set the `maxlength` attribute (`maxLength` property) on the `<input>` element?